# HTML + jQuery dropdown: When any other part of the page is clicked, FadeOut?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, drop-down-menu

This is probably a simple question, but essentially I'm designing an HTML dropdown.

```
$('#bible-trans').click(function() {
    $('#bible-translation-list').fadeToggle('fast');
});
```

Where `#bible-trans` is the main dropdown button, the content of the dropdown is `#bible-translation-list`. So when I hit the main dropdown, the content toggles. Simple.

What I'd like to do is if the user hits anywhere ELSE on the page the dropdown fades out.

```
$("*").not('#bible-trans').click(function() {
    $('#bible-translation-list').fadeOut();
});
```

This is what I have right now, but I'm pretty sure it's incorrect—well it obviously is because it doesn't work— when I click to toggle `#bible-trans`, it toggles and then fades away immediately. Am I using the `not()` selector correctly?

**EDIT:** I think this has a lot to do with the fact that `#bible-trans` is a child of * (obviously). Any way that i can work through that?

Answer (score 3):

Heres one way possible of doing it

http://jsfiddle.net/76gUj/29/

```
$(function(){
    $(document).click(function() {
       if($("#anotherDiv").is(":visible")){
           $("#anotherDiv").fadeOut();
       }
     });

   $("#testdiv").click(function(){
       $("#anotherDiv").fadeIn('fast');
       event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Another example by mu is too short

http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/76gUj/32/

Comment: Yeah I think fiddle is almost a requirement when answering anything to do with JS

Comment: You might want to unbind the click handler on `<body>` when you don't need it: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/76gUj/31/ or better http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/76gUj/32/

Comment: Nice, added the second link to the answer as well. Actually I think thats a much better answer, maybe you should post it as a separate answer all together. I don't want to steal credit for it.

Comment: Nice! But I also need to be able to to click on #testdiv and toggle the menu as well. I tried (have mercy— I'm a designer, this is all unmarked territory for me) to add a second if statement (if anotherdiv is visible, fade out, if it's not visible, fade in) but it's no dice. http://jsfiddle.net/76gUj/45/

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that the user will be clicking on the bible-trans dropdown, you could bind the "blur" event to it.

```
$('#bible-trans').blur(function() {
    $('#bible-translation-list').fadeOut();
});
```

This depends on the dropdown being focused at some point.